# Translate to specific point css

Tags: css, transform

Anyway, I'm here to ask if there's anyway to translate a div to a **specific** point. I originally tried *translate()*, only to realize it translates a div by adding the values to it's offset:

*HTML:*

```
<div class="ttd">I move!</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
.ttd {
    -webkit-transition: transform 2s;
    transform: translate(20px, 20px);
}
```

I'm trying to make a div translate to a point *20px* offset from the window's top and left sides. Could anyone please help me with this? Furthermore, is this possible in css?

Answer (score 0):

This will translate the div to 20px offset from the window's top and left side:

```css
.ttd {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-animation: myAnim 0.5s forwards;
    /*-webkit-animation-delay: 2s;*/
    animation: myAnim 0.5s forwards;
    /*animation-delay: 2s;*/
}

@-webkit-keyframes myAnim {
    100% { left: 20px; top: 20px; }
}

@keyframes myAnim {
    100% { left: 20px; top: 20px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="ttd">I move!</div>
```

You might wan't to check out these interesting links about CSS transition and animation:

- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp
- http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/

Comment: He meant move element from current position
 Not from 0,0

Comment: You can start anywhere, doesn't have to be 0,0. If your current absolute position is unknown/not set in CSS you can use JS to set it first. But then it won't be pure CSS.

Comment: This was useful, but I think it would be better to add if you can accomplish this with `translate` to your question.